# How to search for a specific email in a long thread in GMail for Android?

Tags: gmail, search

My inbox is full of long conversations (threads), each of them often having 50 or more emails. I find that the search function in the GMail app on Android is virtually useless with an inbox like this. Is there something I'm missing?

A bit more context: on the desktop web UI, searching for a specific phrase yields results that are conversations. Clicking on one of these opens up that conversation, expanding only the emails that match, as well as highlighting the matching parts. This is good.

On GMail for Android, the same search query yields the same results, and tapping on one of them opens that conversation, however, *only the latest email in the thread is ever expanded*. There's no indication which emails in the long thread actually contain matches. I need to expand each one in turn and read them myself to look for matches, which is of course ridiculous.

Note that refining my search won't help, here. The correct conversations are found, but that's not granular enough. I need the precise *emails* that match.

So again: what am I missing, if anything? Is the GMail app for Android capable of actually giving me precisely relevant results?